# Keyboard Selection in Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm using the chromebook from acer, the C7, which I bought here in Holland. Ever since I'm on Web Applications or on Super User with the chromebook, I'm having trouble writing short cuts like:`I'm` or `I've`.

On my chromebook they appear like this: `Iḿ` or `Iǘe`.

Does anyone know which keyboard I need to select in order for me the write more efficiently those short cuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this Google Groups post and response:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/chromebook-central/uHkXuZ1pGnE/3iKGllDMAEgJ
the accenting behavior is default on some keyboard input modes, like US international.
Try changing to a different keyboard layout, as via the Google support link: http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1059492

Comment: I had to choose an American keyboard..thanks for your answer.